# Inconsistent Auto Inc Values after failed insert

Tags: python, mysql

**Background information**

So I'm fixing up my mass insert script, and i'm trying to make them conform to ACID principles. My schema is separated into 3 different levels, and the one in question is the last level, Products, which contains 3 tables, The main (child) table, Products holds the PK's from the and sold_price tables

product_img Tb: img_id|prod_img , sold_price Tb: sold_id|sold_price

Product Tb: prod_id|item_title|sold_id|img_id|list_id|

A typical insert into the Product table would look like:

```
INSERT Into Product (item_title, sold_id, img_id,list_id) Values( %s,LAST_INSERT_ID(),LAST_INSERT_ID(),%s)
```

Data excerpt: Sold_price has an empty value ( on the site i scrapped, when an item hasn't received any bids they don't put "0" its just null essentially-- i wrote a script to replace empty brackets with zeros, but what to create a more general check for these kinds of errors )

```
{
  "sold_price": [],
  "item_title": ["Utamaro II. Geisha in the Rain, color woodblock print"],
  "prod_img": ["imageLink"],
  "title": ["Historical Sale: Online - Only - Closing Tuesday, March 30th, 2021"
  ]
 }
```

*note: In my script the order of execution goes product_img table first , sold_price second and the Products last.

**Main problem**

To test my db i'm inserting around 36 rows of data. In the middle of my data set there is a key with an empty value. Since I'm looping through the dataset every record up until the offending one gets inserted , and once it gets to the empty value i get a syntax error and the loop is broken.

I have one commit that's placed outside of the for loop so if at any stage of the iteration there's a failure, no inserts actually persist. However the autoinc updates as if the insert never failed

The issue is that since the product_img table gets its value inserted before the empty value is looped through, and all the ones after it didn't, it left the DB in an inconsistent state

So before the failed insert i already had 7 rows , & the autoinc for all the three tables had equal values of 7

Afterwards i still have 7 rows, but the autoinc's are; product_img: 30, sold_price: 29, Product: 29

This gives me an Integrity error when inserting valid data, due to the last_insert_id passing in the id for the sold_price .

I've also noticed that the order of my inserts affects this to a degree. if i move the empty value to the product_img instead of the sold price, there's no inconsistent autoinc's because no part of the row was inserted.

However when scraping data i'll never know where the offending data point will be, so i think it's reasonable to try and check against a failed transaction throwing the increments off balance?

So tldr, My problem isn't in the sequential order of the auto increment but in making sure that tables within the same level have equal values after a failed insert to avoid integrity issues

edit: Reproducible code

```
curr.execute(""" CREATE TABLE `product_img` (
                `img_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
                `prod_img` varchar(500) Not Null
                            )""")


curr.execute(""" CREATE TABLE `sold_pricei` (
                `sold_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY ,
                `sold_price` int Not Null
                            )""")

curr.execute(""" CREATE TABLE `Product` (
                `prod_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
                 item_title varchar(100) Not Null,
                `sold_id` int NOT NULL,
                `img_id` int NOT NULL,
                

                Index idx_sold (sold_id) ,
                Constraint fk_Product_sold_pricei FOREIGN KEY(sold_id) REFERENCES sold_pricei (sold_id)  On Update Cascade On Delete Restrict,

                Index idx_img (img_id),
                Constraint fk_Product_product_img FOREIGN KEY(img_id) REFERENCES product_img (img_id)  On Update Cascade On Delete Restrict

 )""")

config.commit()
```

.

```
for row in real_data:
    curr.execute(
        """INSERT Into product_img (prod_img)  value (%s) """,
        (
            row["prod_img"]

        ))

    curr.execute(
        """ insert into Sold_Pricei (sold_price) value (%s) """,
        (
            row["current_bid"]

        ))

    curr.execute(
        """INSERT Into Product (item_title, sold_id, img_id) Values( %s,LAST_INSERT_ID(),LAST_INSERT_ID()) """,
        (
            row["item_title"][0],

        ))


config.commit()
```

The json is coming from the Auction sites that i scrape. To test it i just insert the data with all the values accounted for, then one with an empty value, then after that i do another valid insert

Comment: Where's that JSON (?) coming from? [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables (paste the **text**, don't use images), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: Well, let me know if you've got any Toshikatas

Comment: @stickybit Thanks, just added the create statements and isolated the problem. As far as the desired result it just for the failed insert to not mess up the consistency of the db and stop valid inserts from being commited. Once i figure out how to convey that in tabular form i'll upload it.

Comment: @Strawberry Why of course